# Conver json code into php array

Tags: php, json, api

This is my code iv need to convert PHP code

```
{  "Parameter": {  "LookupName": "EmailAddress",
            "LookupValue": "asdasd@fgdfg.dfg"
        },
        "Columns": {  "Include_CSV": "ProspectID",
            "FirstName": "",
            "LastName": "",
            "EmailAddress": ""
        },
        "Sorting": {   "ColumnName": "FirstName",
            "Direction": "1"
        },
        "Paging": { "Offset": 0,
            "RowCount": 200
        }
    }
```

for sending details to api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $json='{"Parameter": {  "LookupName": "EmailAddress",
            "LookupValue": "asdasd@fgdfg.dfg"
        },
        "Columns": {  "Include_CSV": "ProspectID",
            "FirstName": "",
            "LastName": "",
            "EmailAddress": ""
        },
        "Sorting": {   "ColumnName": "FirstName",
            "Direction": "1"
        },
        "Paging": { "Offset": 0,
            "RowCount": 200
        }
    }';
    $array = json_decode($json,true);
?>
```

Read [json-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
$json = '{  "Parameter": {  "LookupName": "EmailAddress",
            "LookupValue": "asdasd@fgdfg.dfg"
        },
        "Columns": {  "Include_CSV": "ProspectID",
            "FirstName": "",
            "LastName": "",
            "EmailAddress": ""
        },
        "Sorting": {   "ColumnName": "FirstName",
            "Direction": "1"
        },
        "Paging": { "Offset": 0,
            "RowCount": 200
        }
    }';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($array);
```

#### Output

```
array (size=4)
  'Parameter' => 
    array (size=2)
      'LookupName' => string 'EmailAddress' (length=12)
      'LookupValue' => string 'asdasd@fgdfg.dfg' (length=16)
  'Columns' => 
    array (size=4)
      'Include_CSV' => string 'ProspectID' (length=10)
      'FirstName' => string '' (length=0)
      'LastName' => string '' (length=0)
      'EmailAddress' => string '' (length=0)
  'Sorting' => 
    array (size=2)
      'ColumnName' => string 'FirstName' (length=9)
      'Direction' => string '1' (length=1)
  'Paging' => 
    array (size=2)
      'Offset' => int 0
      'RowCount' => int 200
```

Access it

```
echo $array['Parameter']['LookupValue']; // Returns asdasd@fgdfg.dfg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['jsonvalue']);
```